# onFocus not working in Chrome, Firefox, Safari

Tags: javascript

I have a Question...  I'm calling one function under onFocus event, and that function is not working properly under onFocus event, yet when I put that function under onMouseOver, it was working perfectly.... why not when running the function under onFocus event??

The html code is below::

```
<a href="#" onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore()" onmouseover="MM_swapImage('Image4','','./Images/Search1.gif',1);" onfocus="commonSearchValidation('company','companyname','branchcode','isactive'); chkSpecial('company'); chkSpecial('branchcode');" onclick="clickSearch('company','branchcode','companyNameOpr','companyname','isactive');" >
                <img src="Images/Search.gif"  alt="Search"     name="Image4" width="73" height="21" border="0" id="Image4" /></a>
```

And the function I am calling is below:

```
function commonSearchValidation()
{   
    var counter=arguments.length;   

    var resflag = false;        
    for(var i=0 ; i < counter ; i++)
    {
        var fvalue = document.getElementById(arguments[i]).value;
        if(fvalue.trim().length!=0)
        {           
            resflag = true;
        }                   
    }
    if(resflag)
    {   
        return resflag;
    }
    else
    {
        alert(Enteronefield);
        document.getElementById(arguments[0]).focus();
        return resflag;
    }
}
```

Comment: Use firebug, press f12 and than switch the console tab and you will get your answers

Comment: i saw in firebug, i am getting unexpected error with jquery1.2.6.js....  on this line..  if ( name == "selected" && jQuery.browser.safari )
    elem.parentNode.selectedIndex;

Comment: You're passing parameter.  But there is no sign of that in your function definition.

Comment: it is dynamically taking all the parameter and it is working fine for IE*...

Comment: `a` element can't receive focus (in any browser) without adding a `tabindex` to the `a`.

Answer (score 0):

Because you misunderstood about what on focus means . Its different from onmouse over.

```
<a href="#" onfocus="myFunction(this)">onfocus</a>
<br>
<br>
<a href="#" onmouseover="myFunction(this)">onmouseover</a>
```

and the js code

```
 function myFunction(x)
    {
    alert("This is "+x.text);
    document.getElementById("a2").focus();   
    }
```

Here is the working [**[JSfiddle DEMO][1]**](http://jsfiddle.net/JQLXa/2/) . Understand the difference.

Comment: now i got the answer in previous comments... by using tabindex in <a> it will work onfocus...

Comment: yeah that is what I meant. check the demo fiddle